# Save result for multiple request

Tags: orientdb, pyorient

I made a python batch that compare a filtered dataset of vertex with a specific vertex. My issue is that I need to execute more than 35000 times this batch. (with the same filtered dataset)

At first, I was querying this filtered dataset every time (30sec/request):

```
SELECT @rid FROM Expression WHERE OUT("identifie").asList().size() > 3
```

Then, I decided to saved all the rids from this dataset on a python variable and select it from rids in every request. (5sec/request) :

```
LET $filtered_expressions = (SELECT FROM [92:0, 92:1, ... , 98:2])
```

So, I'm wondering, can I save this filtered dataset in the database memory or something like that to improve my batch because it's this thing that cost the most time in every request ?